# SSIS - DMA doesn't support migration assessment to SSIS in local SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, upgrade, sql-server-2019

we will migrate from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2019 in near future, we already run DMA to analyze database, however DMA 5.2 doesn't support migration assessment type for intergration services (SSIS)  when the destination server is a local SQL Server, only supports Azure SQL Database ou Azure SQL Managed Instance,

As stated in "assessment for migrating SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS) packages to Azure SQL Database or Azure SQL Managed Instance, by using Data Migration Assistant."  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-assess-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15

Any alternative to evaluate SSIS code compatiblity with new version?

Only option i could find was executing DTexec with Validate parameter (and i don't know if is even similar to DMA):

/Va[lidate]: (Optional). Stops the execution of the package after the validatation phase, without actually running the package. During validation, use of the /WarnAsError option causes dtexec to treat a warning as an error; therefore the package fails if a warning occurs during validation.

Best Regards,
Carlos

Comment: That scenario is not an Azure Migration, and is covered by the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi @David Browne, the page you shared as incorrect information: Before Upgrading Integration Services

We recommended that you run **Upgrade Advisor** before you upgrade to SQL Server 2019 (15.x). **Upgrade Advisor** reports issues that you might encounter if you migrate existing Integration Services packages to the new package format that SQL Server 2019 (15.x) uses.  Upgrade Advisor is data migration assistant since 2016. And i'm preparing the upgrade, not running the upgrade. Thanks

Comment: You are correct.  I thought the old SSIS upgrade advisor was still on the install media.  So  you can assess for Azure and ignore issues that don't apply.  But you'll want to move to project deployment and SSISDB if possible, which will be an additional assesment.  So just create a new SSIS Project add your packages (which will upgrade them) and see if you get any issues.